# PHP preg_replace not working / weird string type / number of characters not adding up

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to remove the following specified characters from a string:

```
<
&
"
#
%
```

So something like:

```
Test%#"&<value
```

should become:

```
Testvalue
```

The order of characters is immaterial.

---

There's something weird about the string type.

A test string looks like this:

```
var_dump($test): string(25) "A BCDEFG/<&"#%/HI"
```

The number of characters is NOT adding up to 25 and I'm not sure why.

---

If I do:

```
$displayName = strtr($displayName, array('<' => '', '&' => '', '"' => '', '#' => '', '%' => ''));
```

I get:

```
 string(20) "A BCDEFG/lt;quot;/HI"
```

Comment: Hey, @matt_tm, just a tip... If you only cared about certain characters, you should have mentioned that on your question. By reading your question, we don't know what exactly you want to do, so it's difficult to help. Try to explain what you have, what is the the expected output, and what you are getting instead.

Comment: ah okay - lemme clarify in the main body...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with regular expressions:

```
<?php
$displayName = 'A BCDEFG/<&"#%/HI';
$displayName = preg_replace('/[\<&"#%]/', '', $displayName);
echo($displayName);
?>
```

This outputs:

```
A BCDEFG//HI
```

Comment: displayName before='A BCDEFG/<&"#%/HI' displayName after='A BCDEFG/lt;quot;/HI'

Comment: (using exactly what you proposed)

Comment: using var_export($displayName, TRUE) to output via email (just fyi) - script is in such a place that i can't output to screen

Comment: You are being fooled by `var_dump`. It is outputting HTML-compatible data somehow (or more likely: it is being HTML-encoded later). Try with `echo`, or writing the string to a file using `file_put_contents`.

Comment: @Vegard - you were right!! displayName before=A BCDEFG/&lt;&&quot;#%/HI

Comment: @matt_tm Ah, of course. If `$displayName` was `A BCDEFG/&lt;&&quot;#%/HI` instead of `A BCDEFG/<&"#%/HI` that would have messed up the replace.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping the `<` will [work](http://www.ideone.com/rXqaG):

```
$displayName = preg_replace('/\<&"#%/', '', $displayName);
```

**However** the surrounding `/` serve as delimiters for the `preg_*` family. Therefore, you must do the following to remove these, too:

```
$displayName = preg_replace('|/\<&"#%/|', '', $displayName);
```

(Here I use `|` as delimiter instead since this character is not part of the expression itself.)

---

**EDIT**
If you're just interested in replacing the characters `<`, `&`, `"`, `#`, and `%`, this is probably preferable:

```
$displayName = str_replace(array('<', '&', '"', '#', '%'), '', $displayName);
```

**EDIT 2**
A great deal of confusion later, it seems that the `$displayName` string did actually contain `A BCDEFG/&lt;&&quot;#%/HI`. In that case you could replace the HTML entities directly (untested):

```
    $displayName = str_replace(array('&lt;', '&quot;', '&', '#', '%'), '', $displayName);
```

Comment: I only care about the following characters - <&"#% and not about the slashes

Comment: @jensgram  $displayName = preg_replace('/\<&"#%/', '', $displayName); didn't work...

Comment: @matt_tm Are you replacing the characters `<`, `&`, `"`, `#`, and `%` *only* if they are directly surrounded by `/`? If not, you are probably better off with plain `strtr()`.

Comment: @matt_tm It did in my link. How do you use `$displayName` afterwards?

Comment: $displayName = strtr($displayName, '<&"#%', '');
echo "displayName=$displayName" showed: displayName=In/<&"#%/ there

Comment: @matt_tm See [here](http://www.ideone.com/Hh5tF): `strtr($displayName, array('<' => '', '&' => '', '"' => '', '#' => '', '%' => ''));`

Comment: @jensgram - thanks, i'll give that a shot.. but can you have a look at the edit? Its weird!

Comment: @matt_tm Weird indeed. Looks like something is transforming the output. Have you tried outputting via `var_dump()` (in order to see the string length, too).

Comment: var_dump() BEFORE showed: string(24) "ABCDEFG/<&"#%/HI" var_dump() AFTER showed: string(19) "ABCDEFG/lt;quot;/HI"

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the **"number of characters not adding up"** part: It used to be true that one char was one byte, but you can't count on that any more. My *guess* is that var_dump() shows how many bytes the string is internally, which you really should not care about.

When working with strings in high-level languages you really should concentrate on number of characters and forget how many bytes a string is. (there are exceptions, of course ;)